# error with by MediaMetadataRetriever setdatasource

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have a problem with the MediaMetadataRetriever setdatasource method. i created a simple project. the main.xml has only a textview, which should display the paramter of the music.mp3. the mp3 is in the project raw file. the mainActivity looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tvMain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_songParam);
    // load data file
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    metaRetriever.setDataSource(R.raw.music);

    String out = "";
    // get mp3 info
    out += metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
    out += "\n";
    out += metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    out += "\n";
    //out += metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
    //out += "\n";
    //out += metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_YEAR);
    //out += "\n";
    // convert duration to minute:seconds
    String duration = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long dur = Integer.parseInt(duration);
    String seconds = String.valueOf(dur % 60);
    String minutes = String.valueOf(dur / 60000);
    out += "Length: [ " + minutes + "m" + seconds + "s ]\n";

    // close object
    metaRetriever.release();
    // display output
    tvMain.setText(out);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

what i am doing wrong here in the line, where i set the data source?? i dont understand that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an integer to setDataSource because R.raw.music returns the resource id related to the file, not the path to the file. You need to pass path or file descriptor as an argument to setDataSource. Try this code:

```
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.music);
    if (afd != null) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
    }
```

Comment: thanks william for your help. i solved it already by using this code:
String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/music";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriever.setDataSource(getApplication(), uri);

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use something like that:

```
final AssetFileDescriptor afd=getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.music);
final MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever=new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My solution goes in the same direction as @android developer's.

Check if you can extract meta data information from the video via `ExtractMetadata`. If not, there might be something wrong with the `setDataSource()` call or the video is in a wrong format/codec.

This code works for me.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd=getAssets().openFd("t.mp4");
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

I had to provide `afd.getStartOffset()` and `afd.getLength()`

Maybe it helps you get on the right track.